# how to host git repository via ssh on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: server, git, project-management

I want to create git server and want to host a java project which has been written in 3 tier archituctere, it means that their might be multiple project(git repository) such as client, server, common etc. to all other developers with their own credential(username, password). The other developers will pull and commit through their own username and password. I don't know how it is to be done even I had search different sites and forume but I din't get it.
plz help me from scretch.

Comment: do you wish to use the webgit interface?

Comment: no I want to host git repo via ssh

Comment: if you wish to hist git via ssh, you don't require a server, because of you are able to access git repo via `git+ssh` protocol.

Comment: thanks for your reply.Can you provide me any resources or ideas how it is to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Common approach to organize `ssh` repo on a server. Just create a folder `/git` in root folder, then assign a group to it with write permissions, and all the users, which be able to read or write to the repo, assign to the group. So a user can create git repo:

```
$ cd /git
$ mkdir project-1
$ cd project-1
$ git init
$ touch README
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Of course you should have the properlt setup users account on both local and remote PCs. So for example, we create the user account `user1` on local PC, and `user2` on the remote one:

```
$ sudo useradd user1
$ ssh sudo useradd user2
$ sudo remote_pc -c 'sudo useradd user2'
```

Then we should be able to issue `git` commands: `clone`, `pull`, and `push`:

```
$ git clone git+ssh://user2@remotepc/git/project-1
$ cd project-1
$ git pull
$ git push
```

Ypu also should know on how to [configure passwordless access to remote `git` repo via `ssh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595848/configuring-git-over-ssh), and to [setup `git-shell`](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html).

Comment: now how to add multiple user and assign password to each of them and what happend when multiple project such as server.git,client.git,common.git etc. I mean should I provide username and password for each repository or not?

Comment: @anondren if a user is require to be a just git, see on last link in the answer, ot others cases, just use linux user records

Comment: sir, suppose if there are dhiren and anon users which they want to access client.git repo then does they can able to provide dhiren@192.168.1.115:/srv/client.git command?

Comment: who shell provide that command?

Comment: @anondren if you'll organize users named `dhiren` and `anon` at the server.the access to repo will be allowed

Comment: you mean it will accessable only if the client.git has defined users credentials?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19486/discussion-between---and-anondren).

Comment: @anondren I've updated the answer